# eval in bash_profile throws error

Tags: bash, eval

currently in my ~/.bash_profilee , I am using the following code to display the current git branch :

```
...
EXPORT ..
....
# Git branch in prompt.
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
```

Now I need to add an eval() in this ~/.bash_profile
so I modified it :

```
    ...
EXPORT ..
....
# Git branch in prompt.
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
eval "$(/Users/myself/Developments/bitbucket/idbox/bin/idbox init -)"
```

But it's now raison an error , when I source it :

```
bash: parse_git_branch: command not found
```

what could be wrong in it ?
thnaks for feedback

Comment: Please replace `eval` by `echo` and add output to your question.

Comment: That function is overly complicated for its purpose. `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` should do the same thing much more simply.

Comment: Thanks Etan, you put me on the right tracks , I updated my old .bash_profile to simply use :
export GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=1
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
export PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\u@\h:\w" "\\\$ "'

Answer (score 0):

updated the .bash_profile to simply use :

```
export GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=1
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
export PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\u@\h:\w" "\\\$ "'
```

Comment: Functions, like variables, are not exported by default. You can make it available with `export -f parse_git_branch`, but you should really consider turning it into a script so it can be invoked by anything, not just bash scripts.